# Working with the YouTube API safeSearch parameter and the q parameter for additional restrictions

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm working with the YouTube API and have set the `safeSearch` parameter to `strict`, but I also want to add additional restrictions to exclude videos that contain words that are not being excluded from the strict filter. As per the YouTube documentation, this can be done using the [`q`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#q) parameter:

> The `q` parameter specifies the query term to search for.
>
> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the `q` parameter value to `boating|sailing`. Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the `q` parameter value to `boating|sailing -fishing`. Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is `%7C`.

Now I've set a piece of my code to currently look like this:

```
part: 'snippet, id',
q: q,
safeSearch: 'strict',
```

If I wanted to exclude videos with titles that contain "boating" or titles that contain "sailing" what would the `q` parameter need to be changed to.

Comment: Could you show us a little more of your code, specifically how q is being set. Have you tried changing q as per the documentation using the negative filters as it suggests?

Comment: This is the current and this code works if I want only boating and sailing videos to show up: part: 'snippet, id',
   q: 'sailing|boating',
   safeSearch:'strict',
   type:'video',    but how would I exclude sailing and boating from showing up? I did try using the above code but the minus sign(-) doesn't seem to work. If I set the q parameter to q: -'boating' the filter doesn't seem to work correctly.